# DateTime range errors is one day off

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework

I've a table that contains timestamps like this:

| DateAdded |
| --- |
| 2023-07-14 08:15:38.1487803 |
| 2023-07-14 08:13:31.4134359 |
| 2023-07-14 08:13:31.4134358 |

In the model this field is defined as

```
DateTime DateAdded {get; set; }
```

I like to query all the records added on July 14 like this.

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14);
DateTime to = from.AddDays(1);
DbSet<Items> dbSet = ...;
IList<Items> result = await dbSet.Where(x => x.DateAdded >= from && x.Added <= to).ToListAsync();
```

This returns 0 rows because the query basically looks like this:

```
WHERE DateAdded >= '2023-07-14T00:00:00.000000' AND DateAdded <= '2023-07-15T00:00:00.000000
```

I suppose because it's a string comparison, the "T" from the query is always after the " " from the table and therefore returns 0 rows.

How can I modify the table/query to correctly return the rows?

Substracting one day from from/to probably returns the correct data because the query is now like this:

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(2023, 7, 14).AddDays(-1);
DateTime to = from;
```

```
WHERE DateAdded >= '2023-07-13T00:00:00.000000' AND DateAdded <= '2023-07-14T00:00:00
```

which does not look correctly although it somehow works.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? EF? EF Core? If EF Core - which one?

Comment: Currently EF Core 7.0.4

Comment: Was not able to repro. Works just fine for me.

Comment: Would you mind uploading your code somewhere for me to try out? Maybe I can spot a difference

Comment: Yes, sure - [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/10pUQD). See the 3 printed out. Also one of my other attempts resulted in logging output containing exactly needed format with space. What culture are you running this with (i.e. what is the computer/program culture set)?